# Create an empty stream from a string on which Stream.Read() waits when no data

Tags: c#, string, stream, tcpclient

I am trying to replace the stream i get from `TcpClient.GetStream()` by a stream I create from a string.

I am using the following method to create said Stream:

```
public Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(s);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

However this stream is read by using `Stream.Read()` somewhere in a library i do not WANT to change. The problem is I create this stream with an empty string because the object needs a stream to start up, normally when using the `TcpClient` stream it would stop at `Stream.Read()` until it would have things to read but not with the stream i created from my string.

So my question, how do I create an empty stream to which i can later add data from a string?

Comment: How is this not just a duplicate of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376297/create-a-stream-from-a-string-which-could-replace-the-tcpclient-stream)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Because now the other question has been deleted :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this question is different since it it better worded, more compact and it actually did what i wanted: generate proper answers as opposed to my previous question which I have deleted because i do realize it is a dupe.

Comment: But that's what the [edit] option is for - if you're not getting the answers you want, you should edit your question to improve it - not post a new one.

Comment: Yes @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have tried that with different question but because of the shear amount of questions the old questions just get drowned in new ones so i wanted to try this and it worked like a charm. Is this something that is not allowed?

Comment: It's not recommended - when you make an edit to your question, it should be moved back up the lists - (but you shouldn't *abuse* that mechanic). Posting duplicate questions (even if you delete the older ones) adds more noise. And, had you not already deleted your question I would have posted my answer to your older one and already have closed this as a dupe.

Comment: See also [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: I will refrain from doing this in the future @Damien_The_Unbeliever sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using internally a `BlockingCollection<>` as a queue, you could write something like:

```
public class WatitingStream : Stream
{
    private BlockingCollection<byte[]> Packets = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();

    private byte[] IncompletePacket;
    private int IncompletePacketOffset;

    public WatitingStream()
    {
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Packets.CompleteAdding();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return Packets.IsCompleted; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return Packets.IsAddingCompleted; }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        byte[] packet;
        int packetOffset;

        if (IncompletePacket != null)
        {
            packet = IncompletePacket;
            packetOffset = IncompletePacketOffset;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Packets.IsCompleted)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            packet = Packets.Take();
            packetOffset = 0;
        }

        int read = Math.Min(packet.Length - packetOffset, count);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(packet, packetOffset, buffer, offset, read);

        packetOffset += read;

        if (packetOffset < packet.Length)
        {
            IncompletePacket = packet;
            IncompletePacketOffset = packetOffset;
        }
        else
        {
            IncompletePacket = null;
            IncompletePacketOffset = 0;
        }

        return read;
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        byte[] packet = new byte[count];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, packet, 0, count);
        Packets.Add(packet);
    }
}
```

You use it as a normal stream. The `Write` doesn't block. The `Read` blocks.

Some decisions had to be taken: this `Stream` is "packet" based. It won't `Write` zero-length packets, and a `Read` will return the data of one packet. The `Read` won't continue on the next packet. If there is data remaining in a packet after a `Read`, that data is saved for the next `Read`. The `Dispose()` will stop the `Write` (so if the "client" does a `Dispose()` before the "server", the server will get an exception if it tries to do a `Write`). If the "server" does the `Dispose()` first, the "client" can finish reading the packets still present. Clearly it is possible (easy) to split this class in two classes (one `Server` and one `Client`), where the `Server` keeps the `BlockingCollection<>` and the Client has a reference to the "server". This would solve the "`Dispose()`" anomaly/problem (but would double the code size :-) )